# Shift+RAlt as Caps mode in Linux

Tags: linux, layout

I use custom keyboard layout for Russian (Ru) language.
Capslock button switches the keyboard layout.
From time to time when I compete in fast typewriting I need to switch on Caps mode (that all the letters in upper case).
Standard behavior when Casplock remapped as layout switcher is Ctrl+Shift+Capslock press together, but it really brakes my speed.

In Windows I use Autohotkeys with little script:

```
RAlt::CapsLock
CapsLock::Send, {Alt Down}{Shift Down}{Shift Up}{Alt Up}
```

And it work well. In linux I try

`setxkbmap -option "grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp_led:caps_toggle"`

but it work not that I need. It change  my layout, because Capslock remapped. 
How can I make a turn on the caps mode with Shift+RAlt.